# How to call 'set password' in Django using a fetch request - issue with csrfmiddlewaretoken?

Tags: django, reactjs, fetch, csrf

I'm trying to create a 'reset password' function in my Django / React app. I'm using django-contrib-auth for the back end and most of this is working OK. However I can't get the POST request right in order to actually update the password. Here's the workflow.

1. The user clicks a "forgot password" link and is shown a form where they enter their email address.
2. They receive an email containing a link to click.
3. They click the link and visit a page where they enter their new password twice and click "Submit".

This is where the problem lies. If I use the built-in form generated by  django-contrib-auth, the password is reset correctly. But I want to use a form generated by React, and in that page I'm sending a fetch request to the same endpoint.

Here's a fetch request generated by the form which works:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/reset/Mw/set-password/' -H 'Cookie: meteor_login_token=OG2fh2iVTkn5AOujhdaBXCsetV-CQ1lS6ZLdtrtzFYC; csrftoken=uSEF8NQB0lUpimwfQcOWLt118igo0bQq2gbpTaGq7zvgQMeF4oM2cu3ZwfgmuDOa; sessionid=39awyoab3wouvxmacbzbxez2hrfoa498' -H 'Origin: http://localhost:8000' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8000/api/v1/reset/Mw/set-password/' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data 'csrfmiddlewaretoken=ASbYGmwXWOTKagND1hWHK0DQt5Qo9MPq8gIIrJmM32uBIGv3ftUNb1FOR2QmDeNa&new_password1=sometext&new_password2=sometext' --compressed
```

Here's my fetch request that fails with an error 'The password reset link was invalid, possibly because it has already been used.  Please request a new password reset.':

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/reset/Mw/set-password/' -H 'Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml' -H 'Referer: http://127.0.0.1:3000/reset/Mw/52l-69686a35c125eb3eafd0/' -H 'Cookie: tabstyle=html-tab; csrftoken=8H5chA6Pq5fw1UkRjKWg91EMSK4A91NrKE4TAODlAvPJGfGhQjCDuEYe8Xc1fEN9' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'X-CSRFToken: 8H5chA6Pq5fw1UkRjKWg91EMSK4A91NrKE4TAODlAvPJGfGhQjCDuEYe8Xc1fEN9' --data 'uid=Mw&csrfmiddlewaretoken=8H5chA6Pq5fw1UkRjKWg91EMSK4A91NrKE4TAODlAvPJGfGhQjCDuEYe8Xc1fEN9&password=sometext&password_confirm=sometext&' --compressed
```

It seems likely that the issue is with the csrf token which I'm generating according to [these instructions](https://www.techiediaries.com/django-react-forms-csrf-axios/).

urls.py:

```
# api/urls.py
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),

    path('password_change/', views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
    path('password_change/done/', views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done'),

    path('password_reset/', views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

Here's the cookie generation function:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = $.trim(cookies[i]);
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
```

My fetch request constructor:

```
fetch(`/api/v1/reset/${data.uid}/set-password/`,
    { credentials: 'include', 'method': 'POST', mode: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
    }, 'body': body })
```

My form has a hidden input with the same token:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value={csrftoken} />
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
    Set new password
</button>
```

Everything I've read about django csrf requests says that the cookie in the header and the cookie in the form data must match. However the values set in the working request generated by the default form are not the same as each other. I see also that the working request includes a session id but I don't know if that's important.

Can anybody help me please to understand what values I need to send in my fetch request?

Or if there is some other easy way to create a Password Reset page in React that I have missed, please point me in the right direction!

Comment: Given that error message, what makes you think the problem is to do with the csrf token?

Comment: I imagine the server doesn't know anything except that the tokens aren't valid, so it just gives that standard error message. I previously had an error that the ssrf tokens weren't present, but I fixed that. And I don't know what else would be the problem - it's the only thing I see that is obviously different between the working request and the failing one.

Comment: I could believe that one of the tokens is being salted but I don't know how to reproduce that in my JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe the original token from the URL is encoded in the token - otherwise how does it know which user to update?